# How to map one list to another in python?

Tags: python

```
['a','a','b','c','c','c']
```

to

```
[2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3]
```

and

```
{'a': 2, 'c': 3, 'b': 1}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: It would be most helpful to add at least one line of description.

Comment: this question is being asked every day for the last week

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
>>> x=['a','a','b','c','c','c']
>>> map(x.count,x)
[2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3]
>>> dict(zip(x,map(x.count,x)))
{'a': 2, 'c': 3, 'b': 1}
>>>
```

Comment: The result looks pretty, but it has potential O(n^2) runtime behaviour.

Comment: But he never said anything about performance... this solves the problem, if it's too inefficient that's a different problem to solve.

Comment: That is right -- but did you ever realize what can happen, wenn you run into the O(n^2)-trap? I experienced it, when a simple algorithm killed program performance totally because it happened to be a bigger dataset and the algorithm had such behaviour.

Comment: Relax. You're most likely writing O(n^3) and O(2^n) algorithms all the time, and never even notice them being executed. Solve those problems **if** they happen.

Answer (score 12):

This coding should give the result:

```
from collections import defaultdict

myDict = defaultdict(int)

for x in mylist:
  myDict[x] += 1
```

Of course if you want the list inbetween result, just get the values from the dict (mydict.values()).

Answer (score 8):

On Python ≥2.7 or ≥3.1, we have a built-in data structure [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to tally a list

```
>>> l = ['a','a','b','c','c','c']
>>> Counter(l)
Counter({'c': 3, 'a': 2, 'b': 1})
```

It is easy to build `[2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3]` afterwards.

```
>>> c = _
>>> [c[i] for i in l]   # or map(c.__getitem__, l)
[2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 6):

Use a `set` to only count each item once, use the list method `count` to count them, store them in a `dict` with the item as key and the occurrence is value.

```
l=["a","a","b","c","c","c"]
d={}

for i in set(l):
    d[i] = l.count(i)

print d
```

Output:

```
{'a': 2, 'c': 3, 'b': 1}
```

Comment: for me this is the most simple to understand/implement. Do you know if its slower than using the collections Counter?

Comment: For such trivial examples, implement them both and time them. Don't trust my guesses. Or rather, don't care about the speed at all; you're using Python for simplicity, not performance.

Answer (score 5):

```
a = ['a','a','b','c','c','c']
b = [a.count(x) for x in a]
c = dict(zip(a, b))
```

I've included Wim answer. Great idea

Comment: `c = dict(zip(a, b))` should do it for computing `c`

Answer (score 3):

Second one could be just

```
dict(zip(['a','a','b','c','c','c'], [2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3]))
```

Answer (score 2):

For the first one:

l = ['a','a','b','c','c','c']

map(l.count,l)

Answer (score 1):

```
d=defaultdict(int)
for i in list_to_be_counted: d[i]+=1
l = [d[i] for i in list_to_be_counted]
```