# Python: Convert this list into dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, formatting

I've got a problem , and do not know how to code in python.

I've got a `list[10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 30]`

I want it be in a dictionary like this

```
{"10": 1, "20":  3, "30" : 1}
```

How could I achieve this?

Comment: If you are counting the number of items in that list, wouldn't it be `{"10": 3, "20":3, "30":1}`? If not, how is this dictionary compiled? What are the values in relation to their keys?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get item count from list in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401885/how-to-get-item-count-from-list-in-python)

Comment: defaultdict solves all problems

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter
a = [10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 30]
c = Counter(a)
# Counter({10: 3, 20: 3, 30: 1})
```

If you really want to convert the keys to strings, that's a separate step:

```
dict((str(k), v) for k, v in c.iteritems())
```

This class is new to Python 2.7; for earlier versions, use this implementation:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576611/

---

Edit: Dropping this here since SO won't let me paste code into comments,

```
from collections import defaultdict
def count(it):
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for j in it:
        d[j] += 1
    return d
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way that does not use `set` or `Counter`:

```
d = {}
x = [10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 30]
for j in x:
    d[j] = d.get(j,0) + 1
```

EDIT: For a list of size 1000000 with 100 unique items, this method runs on my laptop in 0.37 sec, while the answer using `set` takes 2.59 sec. For only 10 unique items, the former method takes 0.36 sec, while the latter method only takes 0.25 sec.

EDIT: The method using `defaultdict` takes 0.18 sec on my laptop.

Comment: If this is a performance race, check the defaultdict version I put in my answer (blame SO for not letting me paste it here), which is about twice as fast.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. You are exactly right: your method ran in 0.18 sec on my laptop.

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
l = [10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 30]
uniqes = set(l)
answer = {}
for i in uniques:
    answer[i] = l.count(i)
```

`answer` is now the dictionary that you want

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

in Python >= 2.7 you can use dict comprehensions, like:

```
>>> l = [10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 30]
>>> {x: l.count(x) for x in l}
{10: 3, 20: 3, 30: 1}
```

not the fastest way, but pretty suitable for small lists

#### UPDATE

or, inspired by inspectorG4dget, this is better:

```
{x: l.count(x) for x in set(l)}
```