# How can I "map" a dict to change only the values in Python

Tags: python, functional-programming

I have a dict like this:

```
food_to_food_type = {"apple": "fruit", "green bean": "vegetable", "tomato": "controversial"}
```

I have a function that wants a dict where keys are food types and values are the number of foods belonging to that type that I want, e.g.:

```
num_foods_of_type = {"fruit": 1, "vegetable": 1, "controversial": 1}
```

In this case, I want an equal number of foods of each type, which I'll represent with a constant.

Is there an easy way to make a new dict by taking the values of my `food_to_food_type` dict, and using them as keys in my `num_foods_of_type` dict, setting the values of each to my constant?

Here's the behaviour I want:

```
NUM_FOODS_DESIRED = 1
num_foods_of_type = {}
for food_type in food_to_food_type.values():
    num_foods_of_type[food_type] = NUM_FOODS_DESIRED
```

But I want to do this in a functional fashion so I can just transform the food_to_food_type dict on the way into my function:

```
order_food_types(magic_maplike_function(food_to_food_type.values(), NUM_FOODS_DESIRED))
```

Of course, I can write `magic_maplike_function` myself, but surely there must be a Pythonic way to do this, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A wonderful solution was proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2401927/1025391) to count the number of occurence in a python list.
This can be applied to your case:

```
values = food_to_food_type.values()
dict( zip( values, map( values.count, values ) ) )
```

Apparantly, I haven't read your question sufficiently careful. You meant something like this: (?)

```
values = food_to_food_type.values()
dict( zip( values, [NUM_FOOD_TYPES]*len(values) ) )
```

Comment: I'm accepting this answer over Cédric's simply because the form that counts the occurrences is also extremely useful, even if it is not what I needed in this case. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve what you need this way :

```
dict(zip(food_to_food_type.values(), food_to_food_type.values()*[NUM_FOODS_DESIRED]))
>>> {'vegetable': 1, 'fruit': 1, 'controversial': 1}
```

Comment: dict(zip(food_to_food_type.values(), len(food_to_food_type.values())*[NUM_FOODS_DESIRED])) to be precise

Comment: and probably the most pythonic way would be dict(zip(food_to_food_type.itervalues(), len(food_to_food_type)*[NUM_FOODS_DESIRED]))

Comment: according to [this article](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/2.7.html#pep-3106-dictionary-views) `iteritems()`, `iterkeys()`, and `itervalues()` are no longer necessary from (probably) Python 2.7 and removed in Python 3.x. See also [this article](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3106/).

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> help(dict.fromkeys)
Help on built-in function fromkeys:

fromkeys(...)
    dict.fromkeys(S[,v]) -> New dict with keys from S and values equal to v.
    v defaults to None.
```

Thus,

```
dict.fromkeys(food_to_food_type.values(), NUM_FOODS_DESIRED)
```